# Flask SocketIO Emit to Specific Client with sid

Tags: python, socket.io, flask-socketio

When Using Flask SocketIO for emitting to specific client(instead of default broadcast mode), I am facing issues with putting room=sid in the emit section where its displaying below message.

`TypeError: checkping() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sid'`

Below is my myapp.py file with socketIO emit.

```
@socketio.on("my_event")
def checkping(sid, *args, **kwargs):
    for x in range(5):
        cmd = 'ping -c 1 8.8.8.8|head -2|tail -1'
        listing1 = subprocess.run(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,text=True,shell=True)
        emit('final', {"data1":x, "data":listing1.stdout},room=sid)
        socketio.sleep(1)
```

When using above, the emit never works and gives below error message:

```
TypeError: checkping() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sid'
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working after exploring the [docs](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html). As per it, each connected device is assigned a unique session id. Hence we can refer the sid with request.sid and define it as below.

```
sid = request.sid
emit('final', {"data1":x, "data":listing1.stdout}, room=sid)
```